# How to remove the border of the client area of a window?

Tags: mfc, client, border, area

I don't want the border of a window's client area to be seen. Is there any way to remove them? The window is a SDI(Single Document) window.

I also noticed that the border appeares only on the top and left side of the client area (no on the right and bottom). I was very confused.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What language/platform are you developing in?

Comment: I am using MFC on Visual studio 2005

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this be useful in your case ?

```
BOOL CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
    cs.style = WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE;  // or others you want
    cs.dwExStyle = 0;  // or others you want

    return CFrameWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs);
}
```

That involves overloading [CWnd::PreCreateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yc5skce(VS.80).aspx) in order to modify [CREATESTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632603.aspx) which defines initialization parameters for a windows.

[dwExStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/61fe4bte.aspx) refers to the extended styles.