# How to create a frame less Dialog box?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, modal-dialog, dialog

My goal is to create a frame-less dialog box using MFC, which are plain rectangle like shown in the image,i have basic knowledge of MFC applications.and dialog box,can you please provide some links for the same.

[image]

Comment: Just set the dialog border style to "None" in the designer and set the min/max and system attributes to false.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423529/how-to-remove-the-border-of-the-client-area-of-a-window

Comment: That is not a dialog.  Not MFC either.  Creating a borderless window with a button doesn't require magic, it is just work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy this code

//Oninitdialog()

```
LONG lStyle = GetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
lStyle &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZE | WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_SYSMENU);
SetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle);
```

Second way
Select you Dialog->properties->Border->None